# Refresh each excel sheet with 5-10 seconds

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I have 100 sheets in my excel, and I can't run Refresh All, as it gives me error "[Microsoft] [ODBC Excel Driver] Too many client tasks."
So currently I have to go to each sheet and click "Refresh" button manually after 5-10 seconds delay.
How can I automate "Refresh" on all sheets by clicking one button with 5-10 seconds delay between each refresh?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub RefreshData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
            qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery = False
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox "Refresh complete"

End Sub
```

Alternate method:

```
Sub RefreshData()

    Dim cn As WorkbookConnection

    For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Refresh
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code is not refreshing any sheet, and only displays "Refresh complete" message in the end.

Comment: I've added an alternate method, see if that works for you